# New tag 'fairy-tale' is too similar to existing tag 'fairy-tales' but is distinct, can we create it please?

Tags: discussion, tags

In my recent question about Stephen King's recent book, *Fairy Tale*, it seems that I can't create the necessary tag to represent the book.

[image]

The tag [fairy-tale](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tale) is very similar to the existing tag [fairy-tales](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tales) but is distinct.

The error message told me to discuss this on Meta. I am here on Meta now to discuss it. How do I go about creating the new tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be named [fairy-tale-2022](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tale-2022).

Comment: I like it, but not a lot. It's reasonable enough.

Comment: "Stephen-King's-Fairy-Tale"?